# Qt: Transparent scrollbar

Tags: qt, scroll, transparent

I'd like to make a background of a scrollbar of QListView transparent. It should be painted **over** the content. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2SRs.png). Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with this hack. I just created a new vertical scroll bar, placed it onto viewport and connected it with the original scroll bar. Then I just hidden the original scrollbar :)

You can see the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrQOQ.png

Comment: could you perhaps post the code u used to do this, i'm trying to do the same thing, but it isnt on top of the content but next to it.

Comment: Unfortunately zero code. Therefore not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Subclass it, override the [paint event](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#paintEvent), and [read this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq16-background.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can not find out where is the scrollbar drawn. I've searched in qlistview.cpp, qabstractitemview.cpp and qabstractscrllarea.cpp. Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qt4tutorial/painting/ or anything in http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=qpaintevent+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

GUI style on screenshot is [QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeintroduction.html) i think